# Chrome extensions JS cannot read values from webpages HTML, assume because of permissions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension that reads values in my a websites HTML and stores it to be used in a reply. It only gives me the below error.

```
    javascript.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
        at HTMLButtonElement.function1 (javascript.js:4)
```

I tried adding chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, details, callback) but it did not seem to help.

```
        window.onload= function (){
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function
                function1() {
                var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('mainForm-_RaisedUserTitle').value;

                var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('mainForm-UserTitleDisplay').value;


                var reply = (MyDiv1,MyDiv2);
                console.log(reply);
                document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML = reply;
            })}
```

It should read:

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('mainForm-_RaisedUserTitle').value;
```

and store that value.

**New code**

*background.js*

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    sendResponse({ yourname: "mainForm-_RaisedUserTitle.value" });
    return true;
  });
```

*browser_action.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>

<div id="mainPopup">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<button id="myBtn">press</button>
<p class="reply" ></p>
</div>
```

*inject.js*

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function (response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function
                function1() {
                var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('yourname');
                //var MyDiv1 = 'test';
                // var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('mainForm-UserTitleDisplay').value;
                // var MyDiv2 = 'test1';

                var reply = ('Hello ' + MyDiv1
                    + 'Kind Regards \n'
                    // + MyDiv2
                );
                console.log(reply);
                document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML = reply;
            })
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

*manifest*

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "...",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "src/override/override.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks",
    "chrome://favicon/",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "contentSettings",
    "contextMenus",
    "cookies",
    "fileBrowserHandler",
    "tts",
    "ttsEngine",
    "history",
    "idle",
    "management",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "geolocation",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not related to permissions. The error message says the object is `null` which means there was no such element in the page. You're probably running this code in the wrong context, see [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: I should have added that when i run the Java script in console on the intended website it works fine.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain all the info necessary to pinpoint the problem as there many moving parts in an extension. Can you link the extension zip here?

Comment: Yeah that's fair!
I made a repo with the full code below, thanks for the help.
https://github.com/timothyosm/replies2

Comment: Remove "background" and "browser_action" then add your script in "content_scripts" ([documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)).

Comment: I would piggy back off of @wOxxOm had mentioned, especially if everything works in the console.  Is it possible you're trying to access a frame within the page.  I had the same exact behavior until I realized I was needing to access a frame within the page.  Check the document ID that ('mainForm-_RaisedUserTitle') is located, and verify it's part of a frame/iframe.  If so, you'll need to be within that context for the code to return the results.  Took me a couple of weeks to find the issue.

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys! You're legends. I'll try your suggestions today and report back.

Comment: Okay, i read through the documentation and also used another app to generate the file structure.

I am struggling to get my script to talk to eachother. I can guarantee i'm doing something silly, but im struggling to understand what.

I'm using the below, which i think is correct after doing some googling.
    sendResponse({ yourname: "mainForm-_RaisedUserTitle.value" });

git of all files:
https://github.com/timothyosm/replies-new

Comment: Added updated code to the main post